# Differentiable inverse of a vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If $m>n$ and $f: \mathbb{R^m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$ is differentiable, show that $f$ can not have an differentiable inverse.

Attempt: I tried to show that the Jacobian of $f$ isn't invertible, since it is not an square matrix. Is it a sufficient criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By contradiction, if $f$ has a differentiable inverse, then $\mathrm{d}_0f$ is a bijective linear map between $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$.

After seeing your edit, yes this is correct.